# Использование утверждений в Api тестах codeception

Tags: php, codeception

Имеется тест:

```php
<?php
namespace tests\user;

use tests\ApiTester;

class AttachFacebookCest
{
    public function successAttach(ApiTester $I)
    {
        $I->sendGET('url');
        $response = $I->grabResponse();
//        здесь нужно проанализировать $response при помощи assert
//        ВНИМАНИЕ! $I->seeResponseContainsJson() не подходит
    }
}
```

и конфиг

```
actor: ApiTester
modules:
  enabled:
    - REST:
        depends: [PhpBrowser, Yii2]
        url: http://my-host
    - Yii2:
        part: [orm, fixtures]
```

Собственно вопрос в том как использовать(что подключить) утверждения(они же assert-ы) в данном тесте?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ сам. Нужно добавить в api.suite.yml модуль Asserts:

```
actor: ApiTester
modules:
  enabled:
    - Asserts
    - REST:
        depends: [PhpBrowser, Yii2]
        url: http://my-host
    - Yii2:
        part: [orm, fixtures]
```

и запустить сборку

```
vendor/bin/codecept build
```